# Use assignment operator instead of calling a function in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm fairly new to C++, so it's messing with my googlefu.  I'm just not sure what to ask I guess.

I'm wondering if it is possible to make it so that you can simply use the assignment operator to pass values to objects.

The closest thing I can think of to what I'm talking about is how Python works when you use the @public and @myVar.setter.  You can then say:

```
class MyClass(object):

    @public
    def myVar(self):
        return self._myVar

    @myVar.setter
    def myVar(self, value):
        self._myVar = value;

MyClass.myVar = 12

Print MyClass.myVar
```

This would print 12, but never have to call the myVar method as a function is normally called, "myVarSet(12)" and "myVarGet()".

The reason I ask, is because I understand that "string" is not a true data type, but essentially an array of char.  That would mean that when you include string, it somehow has the ability to do something interesting with the assignment operator.  Instead of having to assign a variable like the following:

```
char word[5] = { "h","e","l","l","o" };
```

You can simply say:

```
string word = "hello";
```

What if one wanted to be able to do something like that with other types of arrays?  Let's say I wanted to have an array of integers and assign them like:

```
Foo intarray = 13235;
```

Instead of saying:

```
Foo intarray;
intarray.setVar(.....)
```

How would I do that?  Is it possible?

Comment: `std::string` is a user-defined class like any other. User-defined classes are true data types.

Comment: As long as you do not make your constructor explicit, you should be able to initialize your objects with whatever you wish. http://codepad.org/cCG0GcUA

Comment: I understand that types are essentially classes.  I am talking about how to assign values directly to the object instead of calling the object's function or variable.

Foo x = 12;
instead of:
Foo x = Foo(12)

Answer (score 0):

All your so-called assignments aren't assignments, but initializations.

```
string word = "hello";
```

is **copy initialization**.

```
string word;
word = "hello";
```

is initialization followed by an **assignment**.

And yes, it's entirely possible, you just need to overload the assignment operator:

```
class Foo{
   Foo& operator = ( whatever );
};
```

**However**, this doesn't seem to be what you want. If I'm not mistaken, you're looking for a way to construct an object using some values, which is what a **constructor** is for:

```
struct Foo{
    Foo(int x) : _x(x) {}
    int _x;
};
```

and now you wouldn't write

```
Foo foo;
foo._x = 5;
```

but directly

```
Foo foo(5);
```

To do

```
Foo foo = Foo(5);
```

you'll also need a publicly visible copy constructor, (in this case, the default, compiler-generated one will do). Also look into the rule of three if you're managing resources.

This is all basic stuff, and trust me, it's narrowed down **a lot** here. You're best off learning C++ using a book.

Comment: I understand constructors and overloading.  I've also been programming for 25 years in various languages.  When I say fairly new to C++, I mean that I know only slightly more than the basics, and I rarely use it.  I think you must misunderstand what I am talking about though.

You are saying that "string word = "hello";" Is copy initialization, which is what I want to do, but you gave a direct initialization method, which I already understand how to do.

Copy initialization is probably what I need to look up though.

Comment: @TimmSimpkins yes it is. **But** it's rarely needed. Why do you need copy- instead of direct- initialization?

Comment: @TimmSimpkins see http://ideone.com/CA2Gqd - this creates a temporary `X` using the `int` constructor, then uses the copy constructor to create `x` from the temporary (theoretically, in practice it's optimized out probably).

Comment: I don't "need" to do it.  I know it can be done, and I want to learn how it is done.  It would make it easier to do some things like Foo x = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; cout << x; and have it print [1,2,3,4] for example, or be able to say Foo x = {{1, 2},{3, 4}}; Foo y = {{5, 6},{7, 8}}; cout << x * y; and it print out the result of a matrix multiplication.

Comment: @TimmSimpkins you can use the `= { }` syntax in C++11 and in C++03 for pod-types.